# Local notifications not showing in notification center (.provisional) / iOS 15.2.1

Tags: apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification, ios15

Has anyone experienced problems with [.provisional] notifications on iOS 15? Can't get anything to show up in Notification Center in 'Quiet Delivery' mode. I'm clueless..

These are relevant extracts:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization([.provisional, .alert])
// -> granted: true

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Test"
content.body = "Test"

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "some_id...", content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification, ...)
// This is called -> returning [.banner] (so it should show in foreground, not that it matters since it's provisional...)
```

BUT ... notifications center is empty.
The same code works fine using non-provisional mode (user granting explicit consent to notifications).

Is there something obvious I might be missing here?

--
**UPDATE:** Ok, not much of an answer, but clear observation:
Putting app into background -> above code does deliver notification into notification center.

This means that .provisional mode completely ignores  'willPresent notification:' return value [which allows presentation in foreground] AND does not deliver notification into notification center if app is in foreground.

I guess I can live with that and it kind of makes sense... (?).

Comment: I've noticed something similar happen if I'm actively looking at the notification center.

e.g. I'm presenting a notification from applicationWillResignActive. I swipe down to see notification center. No notification. If I then hide the notification center, the notification will appear.